# ¿Cómo validar campos con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Mi validación no se hace cuando envío los datos ... la única función que me llama es la de validar

`<script src="../validar.js"></script>`

`<form id="formu" action="registro2.php" method="POST" class="form register" onsubmit="return validar();"  >`

```
function validarc(){

    var nombre,correo,mensaje;
    nombre=document.getElementById("name").value;
email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    mensaje=document.getElementById("mensaje").value;

    if(nombre === "")   
{
   alert("El campo del nombre esta vacío"); 
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
    return false;
    }else if(email=== ""){
     alert("El campo del correo esta vacío"); 
     document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
                }else if(mensaje=== ""){
     alert("El campo del mensaje esta vacío"); 
     document.getElementById("mensaje").focus();
    return false;
                }
}


function validarl(){

    var correo,password5;
    correo=document.getElementById("usuario").value;
password5=document.getElementById("pass").value;

    if(correo === "")   
{
   alert("El campo del correo esta vacío"); 
    document.getElementById("correo").focus();
    return false;
    }else if(password5=== ""){
     alert("El campo contraseña esta vacío"); 
     document.getElementById("password5").focus();
    return false;
                }
}

function hideOrShowPassword(){ 
    var password1,password2,check;

     password1=document.getElementById("password1");
    password2=document.getElementById("password2");
     check=document.getElementById("ver");

    if(check.checked==true) // Si la checkbox de mostrar contraseña está activada
    {
        password1.type = "text";
        password2.type = "text";

    }
    else // Si no está activada 
    {
        password1.type = "password";
        password2.type = "password";

    }
}


function validar(){

    var nombre,usuario,email,sexo,fecha,password1,password2,sexo2;
    nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    usuario=document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    password1=document.getElementById("password1").value;
    password2=document.getElementById("password2").value;
    sexo1=document.getElementById("masculino").checked;

     sexo2=document.getElementById("femenino").checked;
    fecha=document.getElementById("fecha").value;

    if(nombre === "")   
{
   alert("El campo nombre esta vacio"); 
    document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    return false;

    }else if(nombre.length>50 || nombre.length<5){
     alert("Los nombres deben contar entre 5 y 50 caracteres"); 
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    return false;
    }else if(usuario=== ""){
     alert("El campo usuario esta vacio"); 
        document.getElementById("usuario").focus();
    return false;
         }else if(usuario.length>50 || usuario.length<3){
     alert("El nombre de usuario deben contar entre 3 y 50 caracteres"); 
             document.getElementById("usuario").focus();
    return false;
             }else if(password1=== ""){
     alert("El campo contraseña esta vacio"); 
            document.getElementById("password1").focus();
    return false;
                }else if(password1.length>40 || password1.length<6){
     alert("La contraseña debe contar entre 6 y 40 caracteres"); 
       document.getElementById("password1").focus();
    return false;
        }else if(password2=== ""){
     alert("Verifique su contraseña"); 
       document.getElementById("password2").focus();       
    return false;
        }
        else if(email=== "" ){
     alert("El campo email esta vacio"); 
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false; }
        else if(fecha=== null || fecha===""){
     alert("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento"); 
            document.getElementById("fecha").focus();
    return false; 

                }else if(email.length>40){
     alert("Correo muy largo"); 
        document.getElementById("email").focus();          
    return false;}

    if(password1 === password2){
        }else{ 
            alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden"); 
              document.getElementById("password2").focus();
    return false;
            }

 if(sexo1==false && sexo2==false ){
     alert("Indique su sexo"); 
    return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no validas directamente en los controles? Tienes muchos tipos de `input` como `email`, `number` y atributos como `min`, `max`, `required` y `pattern` para realizar validaciones complejas por medio de expresiones regulares.

Comment: prefiero validarlo por javascript ... es que la verdad las validaciones me servían pero de la nada ya no me sirvieron

Comment: Ahí te he puesto un ejemplo que hace lo mismo que tú pero con un código muy reducido por si te sirve igualmente..

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 4):

Podrias intentar validar desde el mismo documento html, adjuntando el script para no tener problemas como el siguiente ejemplo mi amigo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Registro de usuario</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../recursos/favicon.jpg">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    document.formulario.nombre.focus();
    document.formulario.addEventListener('submit', validar);
  }
  function validar(evObject) {
    evObject.preventDefault();
    var ok = true;
    var formulario_registro = document.formulario;
    for (var i = 0; i < formulario_registro.length; i++){
      if(formulario_registro[i].type == 'text'){
        if(formulario_registro[i].value == null || formulario_registro[i].value.length == 0 || /^\s*$/.test(formulario[i].value)){
          alert(formulario[i].name + ' no puede estar vacio o solo contener espacios en blanco.');
          ok = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if(isNaN(formulario_registro.edad.value) == true || /^[1-9]\d$/.test(formulario_registro.edad.value) == false) {
      alert("Edad no valida.");
      ok = false;
    }
    if(isNaN(formulario_registro.noexterior.value) == true) {
      alert("Número exterior invalido.");
      ok = false;
    }
    if(isNaN(formulario_registro.nointerior.value) == true || /^[1-9]\d$/.test(formulario_registro.nointerior.value) == false) {
      alert("Numero interior invalido.");
      ok = false;
    }
    if(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(formulario_registro.correo.value) == false) {
      alert("Direccion de correo invalida.");
      ok = false;
    }
    if(formulario_registro.password.value != formulario_registro.r_password.value) {
      alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
      ok = false;
    }
    if(ok == true) {
      formulario_registro.submit();
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Al dar clic al botón ejecutar este devuelve error. Si no pretendes que el código se ejecute directamente en esta página, no se debería incluir dentro de Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 está disponible desde el año 2012; no hay razón para no aprovechar sus beneficios y esto incluye, la validación de formularios. Ahora puedes usar la validación HTML5 para hacer este proceso mucho más sencillo por medio de atributos como `required` y `pattern` que permiten validaciones complejas *inline*; además de la [API de validación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_HTML5_constraint_validation_API).

**Ejemplo**

```js
const validar = (form) => {
  const {
    username,
    email,
    password,
    repassword,
    sex
  } = form;
  let flag = true;
  
  if (!username.checkValidity()) {
    alert(username.title);
    flag = false;
  }
  else if (!email.checkValidity()) {
    alert(email.title);
    flag = false;
  }
  else if (!password.checkValidity()) {
    alert(password.title);
    flag = false;
  }
  else if (!repassword.checkValidity()) {
    alert(repassword.title);
    flag = false;
  }
  else if (password.value !== repassword.value) {
    alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
    flag = false;
  }
  else if (!sex[0].checkValidity() || !sex[1].checkValidity()) {
    alert(sex[0].title);
    flag = false;
  }
  return flag;
}
```

```css
#sex-area > span,
#sex-area > .radio-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form novalidate onsubmit="return validar(this)">
  <header>
    <h3>Registrarse</h3>
  </header>
  <article>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      name="username" 
      placeholder="Nombre de usuario" 
      pattern="[0-9A-Za-z]{3,50}"
      title="Ingrese un nombre de usuario con solo caracteres alfanúmericos entre 3 y 50 caracteres"
      required
    />
    <input 
      type="email" 
      name="email" 
      placeholder="Correo electrónico" 
      title="Ingrese un correo electrónico válido."
      required
    />
    <input
      type="password"
      name="password"
      placeholder="Contraseña"
      pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,40}$"
      title="Ingrese una contraseña segura: mínimo un mayúscula, número y un carácter especial entre 6 y 40 caracteres"
      required
    />
    <input 
      type="password" 
      name="repassword" 
      placeholder="Verifique contraseña"
      title="Ingrese nuevamente su contraseña"
      required 
    />
    <section id="sex-area">
      <span>Sexo</span>
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="sex" 
          value="m" 
          text="M" 
          title="Seleccione su sexo"
          required 
        />
        M
        <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="sex" 
          value="f" 
          title="Seleccione su sexo" 
          required
        />
        F
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <button>Registrar</button>
  </footer>
</form>
```

Hoy en día tienes varios frameworks y librerías frontend para mostrar los errores de validaciones de forma más amigables, como son [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js), [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) o librerías para [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) plano o [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con un doble igual para comparar valores, el triple igual se utiliza para también comparar el tipo y es más estricto y no necesario para validar un formulario.

```
function validar(){

        var nombre,usuario,email,sexo,fecha,password1,password2,sexo2;
        nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        usuario=document.getElementById("usuario").value;
        email=document.getElementById("email").value;
        password1=document.getElementById("password1").value;
        password2=document.getElementById("password2").value;
        sexo1=document.getElementById("masculino").checked;
        sexo2=document.getElementById("femenino").checked;
        fecha=document.getElementById("fecha").value;

        if(nombre == "") {
         alert("El campo nombre esta vacio"); 
         document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
         return false;
        } else if(nombre.length>50 || nombre.length<5){
         alert("Los nombres deben contar entre 5 y 50 caracteres"); 
         document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
         return false;
        } 
      ...
        else if(!sexo1 && !sexo2){
         alert("Indique su sexo"); 
         return false;
        }

      }
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: probe eso y sigue sin funcionar lo raro es que la validación del login la hice igual y si sirve

Comment: Es extraño porque en principio parece todo correcto. Has comprobado que llegas correctamente a la función validar, por ejemplo haciendo un alert nada más empezar la función?

Comment: eso si no lo he intentado ... porque como tú puedas observar tengo más funcionas y sirve hasta la de hideorshowpassword

Comment: Solo por descartar que el problema sea que no accede

Comment: mm donde debo colocar el alert? o como? ... porque esas validaciones son para un registro entonces no imporrta que los campos esten vacios si le doy a enviar ... pues envía todo a la bdd

Comment: function validar() { alert("estoy dentro"); return false; ....} Así no te envía el form porque siempre tiene return false.